# Port forwarding, iptables apt-get not working

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, apt

I'm currently setting up my server. I use `proxmox` which similar to `vmware`.
Important thing to know is that i only have 1 external IP address. On my server, I forward port 80 and 443 to virtual host `apache` using this command :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.43.113
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.0.43.113
```

My network is also linked with :

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.43.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now the problem is that if I do redirect port 80 & 443 this way, apt-get throws 404 Error when i use it from a VM (behind my gate).

How can I redirect port to my VM by having still apt-get working ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redirect ALL packets to port 80 and 443 to your guest, including its own packets. Add a

```
-i eth0
```

condition to your DNAT rules.

Comment: I don't see why that shall be a problem. If e.g. 10.0.43.112 tries to access the webserver then it will probably try to connect to the external address so this packet from eth1(?) must be DNATted to 10.0.43.113, too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check (with tcpdump) what happens on the webserver? I assume that such a rule is missing (assuming eth1 is your internal interface):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to $INTERNAL_GATEWAY_IP
```

Without this the client tries to connect to 1.2.3.4, the gateway deflects the packet to 10.0.43.113, the webserver sees a connection from the client (e.g. 10.0.43.112) thus sends its reply to 10.0.43.112, and the client having sent to 1.2.3.4 and getting a reply from 10.0.43.113 just goes "WTF?"... But with SNAT the webserver responds to the gateway, the gateway rewrites both source and destination address and everyone's happy.